# How to fix winlogon.exe randomly crashing/hanging my computer?

Tags: windows-xp

I've got these problems:

1) sometimes winlogon.exe crashes at boot-up and my whole computer shuts off once i click "no" to visual-studio-2008 just-in-time-debugger window, takes about 30 secs until my harddrives starts up again, its really scary, i am afraid it is causing hardware malfunctions in long term. this has happened dozen of time now.

2) sometimes i leave the computer alone a while, i come back and i notice ctrl+alt+del doesnt work and winlogon.exe is using 100% of one of my 4 cores.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a virus. Here is a link to some information: http://www.google.ca/search?q=winlogon.exe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Good luck,
Regards,

Comment: just wondering, why my antivirus wont recognize it then? using f-secure internet security 2011. i've scanned whole computer many times and nothing found

Comment: many viruses now use rootkit technology to bypass detection once inside.  i have had to use killbox to remove processes that are hooked into explorer/winlogon.  if you want to do the virus scan reliably, slave the drive into another PC and scan that way

Comment: unfortunately i cant do that... and i cant definitely delete winlogon.exe since its used by windows. suggestions?

Comment: @neeb: I would also download Microsoft Security Essentials - http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/ and Malwarebytes - http://www.malwarebytes.org/ and do complete scans with them.

Comment: Those are pretty good, but if it's a rootkit you'd be out of luck. I recommend running GMER(http://www.gmer.net/) first.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution if it's not a virus(though it sounds like [TDSS](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/solutions?qid=208280684) to me). You can repair system files by going to the start menu -> run
Type CMD
Press Ok
Type SFC /scannow

**MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A GOOD AND CURRENT [BACKUP](http://data-backup-software-review.toptenreviews.com/why-backup-your-computer.html)!!!**

Answer (score 0):

I had winlogon.exe causing an error message and reboot at system startup, but only on maybe 50% of boots. No virus or similar found.

I realised it had started soon after I installed Oracle VM Virtualbox. I deinstalled this and problem has completely gone. Virtualbox does something clever with network connections/cards - I believe that's what caused the problem